# Can't ping localhost/or reach locally hosted domain

Tags: windows-7, networking, localhost

I can’t reach a locally hosted domain, and in testing I have discovered I can’t ping localhost or the actual IP either. The OS is Windows7 64bit, Pro.

DNS works, I can ping others on my network, they can ping me, and they can reach the hosted domain. The *only* problem I have found is that I can’t reach the locally hosted domains!

```
C:\Users\ian>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : leda
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : hcs

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hcs
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 PCI-E Ethern
et Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-23-54-7C-E2-2A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.12(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-88-4A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.205.215(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

C:\Users\ian>ping localhost

Pinging leda [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\ian>ping coachmaster.leda.hcs

Pinging coachmaster.leda.hcs [192.168.0.12] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\ian>
```

I can reach a hosted VM in VirtualBox and the VM can browse the hosted sites.

I’ve removed Zone Alarm and disabled Windows Firewall - same results.

So how can I browse my locally hosted sited? What could be blocking it?

Comment: My old netgear router does that sometimes. All my computers can reach outside ip's but no internal ip's. I just pull the power out of it and wait 30s and then power it up again and the problem is gone (for a month or so).

Comment: I tried the equivalent - turn everything off, restart the linux firewall, restart the rest. It helped me see all the correct machines. But I still can't ping the local machine's IP (192.168.0.?? or 127.0.0.1) from inside, yet others can ping me. Very strange.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? If the others could reach it but not that one system, then the first thing to check would be the `hosts` file.

Comment: Try also showing routing table (netstat -nr).  Can you ping 192.168.0.12 ?  In school, I was taught to re-install the TCP/IP network stack to resolve if cannot ping 127.0.0.1 (although I don't recall having come across that).

Answer (score 0):

Two things first is that you can't browse your locally hosted domain. If you are using a proxy server to reach the internet you need to tell your browser to ignore 192.168.0.0/24 inf Firefox or 192.168.0.* in IE. network or just try direct internet connection without your proxy. As for ping, I would normally assume that ICMP Echo is disabled hence no ping replies, but this is not the case as others are able to ping you.

Another good test is to open a telnet connection to port 80:

```
telnet 192.168.0.12  80
```

Comment: I don't know you mean by can't browse locally hosted domain - I can reach locally hosted websites in Win2K, WinXP, and Linux. But not this Win7 machine. All sites go direct - no proxy (NAT firewall). Ping is enabled, and telnet is not installed. 
Even more confusing - after waiting for 2 hours I can now reach the website, but still not ping localhost or domain. All I've changed is a backup script, and been browsing the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew
```

might help.

Answer (score 0):

I would take it off the domain, reboot... set it to dhcp... put it back on the domain with dhcp. The "ipconfig /release" and "ipconfig /renew" mentioned by John above should have fixed the issue. I think there is another host using the defined ip...

Answer (score -1):

not a real solution, but you can use "leda" instead of "localhost". the DNS cliente should translate to 192.168....

"localhost" name is managed by the DNS, but I understand the DNS client never request the address to the DNS but uses the local address instead.

This is very weird. 
btw, the router has nothing to do with this, localhost is localhost, no outsidehost...

Comment: how is your host file? maybe is damaged, some viruses likes to modify hosts for disabling some AV features. \windows\system32\drivers\etc